# Select image and gif from Camera roll

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building an Ionic app with Angular and Firebase.

I want to be able to upload an image and gif to my firebase database, but I've only been able to get `image` to work. Also, I don't want videos.

My code is as follows:

```
takePhoto(sourceType:number) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 40,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,
      sourceType:sourceType,
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.uploadToStorage(base64Image);
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }

  uploadToStorage(src) {
    this.uploadProgress = true;
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    // Create a timestamp as filename
    this.imageFileName = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + "_" + this.userData.uid;
    // Create a reference to 'images/todays-date.jpg'
    const imageRef = storageRef.child('posts/'+this.imageFileName+'.jpg');
    imageRef.putString(src, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then((snapshot)=> {
      snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
        this.imageURL = downloadURL;
        this.uploadProgress = false;
        this.uploadSuccess = true;
        console.log(this.imageURL)
        this.logEvent("Uploaded Image");
      });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

But this only allows still images. According to the docs for the [Ionic Camera](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)
you can change `mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE` to `mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA` but that doesn't work for me. It works when I'm testing on my computer, but not on iOS or Android.

Any ideas how I can allow images and gifs from being selected? Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is, your not able choose gif images ? if so, just confirm me, what are the files, that you are able to choose.

Comment: @Vasanth exactly, I can't select gifs. I can select regular images like png and jpeg. If I change mediaType to `ALLMEDIA` I can select gif, but it doesn't work on android, and I don't want to be able to select video...

Comment: When you set it to ALLMEDIA, is correct gif file is chosen ? by logging you can check it. If that is working fine, then I will tell you a method to upload the files.

Comment: @Vasanth yes that's fine, but on Android it doesn't let you select any file.. only on iOS it works.

Comment: If you just want to choose the file from mobile device and don't want take image from camera, then use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/. That would very straight and all your problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
photos ; 
 OpenGallery(){
      console.log("taktit");
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM 
      }

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
       // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
       // If it's base64:
       console.log("taktit");
       let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
       this.photos.push(base64Image);
       this.photos.reverse();

      }, (err) => {
       // Handle error
      });  else {    }
    }
```

- Now you can uplode your object photos to your firebase

Comment: Convert the gif to base64 and use them , see at google " convert gif to base64 whit javascript